# front-page.php con tres entradas: una con imagen grande y las otras con imágenes pequeñas

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy terminando mi segundo tema hijo para WordPress y lo que me falta es el loop, etcétera, de **front-page.php** (ahora este archivo solo tiene `get_header`, `get_sidebar` y `get_footer`) para que muestre únicamente las últimas tres entradas marcadas con "Fijar esta entrada en la página de inicio". El resultado que busco es este:

[image: 1]
Obtengo la "imagen entrada 1" con `<?php the_post_thumbnail('post_feat_img') ?>`. La "imagen entrada 2" e "imagen entrada 3", con `<?php the_post_thumbnail('post_feat_img_m') ?>`.

Necesito también que a medida que se publiquen nuevas entradas marcadas con "Fijar esta entrada en la página de inicio", la última de éstas quede como "entrada 1" y el resto cambie de lugar así:

[image]
¿Cómo debería quedar el loop, etcétera, para que el resultado sea lo anterior?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
<?php 
$loopcount = 0;
while (have_posts()) { the_post();
    if ($loopcount == 0) {
        include('parts/content-first.php');
    }else{
        include('parts/content.php');
    }
$loopcount++;
}
```

Usando tu ejemplo con boostrap como ejemplo, solo tienes que meter todo el codigo dentro de un div.row y que el codigo de content-first.php este todo dentro de un `div.col-md-12` y en el content.php dentro de un `div.col-md-6`

Lo de que salga de primero la entrada fijada ya lo hace el loop de Wordpress por defecto.

Comment: ¿Y en "content-first.php" y "content.php" qué código debe ir? Recuerda que necesito que solo aparezcan las entradas marcadas con "Fijar esta entrada en la página de inicio"...